# Quick and easy mining on OS X

Tags: mac, miner-configuration

I am new to Bitcoins, and I'd like to get started mining, but I'm on OS X. I've tried several different mining applications, and none of them have worked for me. I've got nothing but errors. Is there a mining application that has quick and easy setup?

I have tried [DiabloMiner,](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/DiabloMiner) [RPC Miner,](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/RPC_Miner) and one other that I can't remember the name of. I will put it up here if I find it.

Comment: Why don't you list the ones you've already tried, to start everyone off on the same page?

Comment: what errors are you getting with RPC Miner? The CPU miner should work for you, but you won't get much with a CPU. I would warn that Mac laptops seemed to become hotter than would be safe for the hardware when GPU mining and iMacs are probably the same... at the very least run smcfancontrol and ramp up the fans if you want to mine on a mac

Answer (score 5):

Try the [DiabloMiner app](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=8994.0). It uses an older version of Diablo Miner that should work. The developers behind bitcoin mining software usually do not put much effort into Mac compatibility mainly because of two aspects:

- Most Macs (iMac/Macbook/Macbook Pro) are not suited for mining because they have poor ventilation, which causes overheating issues.
- Apple's OpenCL implementation is not very good. There are [constant complaints](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=29960.msg380025) about its inefficiency and incompatibility with mining software.

Comment: I ran it and got: `ERROR: OpenCL platform Apple contains no devices
`

Comment: @daviesgeek what is your computer model and OSX version? You might not have OpenCL support in your card.

Comment: I have a MBP 8,1 and OS 10.6.8

Comment: @daviesgeek You have an Intel HD Graphics 3000 so you can't mine with that. Check [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison) for a list of supported GPUs